# Is Qt 3D studio available for 32 bit os?

Tags: qt, qt3d

I just installed it, and upon trying to launch it, I got the "this is a 64-bit app". The Qt Creator is working though.

I used the "qt-unified-windows-x86-3.0.2-online.exe" from the official site to install it. Why this installer was so dumb to install a 64-bit app on a 32-bit computer is a mistery to me. This is probably due to me selecting a mirror to install with the "QtSdkRepoChooser-v1.1.0-windows_x86.zip" tool, since it failed originally.

Can I still make 3D apps without 3D studio? All I need right now is just a simple rotating triangle, with a few buttons to start/stop rotation.

Comment: It depends.What system are you using?

Comment: @ShiheZhang windows 7, 32bit.

Comment: Since some 64bit system would also use the x86 installer, so it may install the 64-bit app on purpose. And the Qt 3D studio may support 64 bit only you need to find the explanation on the official site.